# Is there a way to open a file browser view within Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, customization, eclipse-juno

I am working on using Eclipse as a basic file editor, without all the heap issues that comes with a Java tools install. I downloaded the platform version with no plugins, and added some editing tools for the code I wish to develop.

I do not intend to create new projects in this Eclipse, but would rather just edit individual files. Ideally, I can just open these from a File Explorer view within Eclipse (see image). Is there a plugin that I can download that will allow me to do this, or is there a simple hack to get this feature added?

[image]

Comment: Search for `File View` in the views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. It unfortunately adds nearly 30MB, and I was really hoping for a lighter weight solution (I will not choose this as the answer yet, in the event one is posted). The [Target Management plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/tm/) provides a plugin (add this url to Eclipse's *Install New Software...* dialog: http://download.eclipse.org/tm/updates/3.4/ ) that allows the browsing of remote and local file systems. Opening the view *Remote Systems* will allow you to open the local file system and open files from within, that appear in the main editor window.